# Options leqno, reqno for documentclass or exist another option?

Tags: math-mode, equations, numbering, align, amsmath

I consider these simple MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
     x^n + y^n = z^n
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

With the option `leqno` we know that `LaTeX` puts the progressive number of the equation on the extreme left. With the option `reqno` at the extreme right of the page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
     E=mc^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

But when I have, for example a code with `align` option, knowing that the number can be either on the first or second equation, how come the `leqno` option is not active and the number is always put on the right?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a &= b+c \nonumber\\
e &= f+g
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

1. How do I put the number of the equation between the two equations in the middle or at left or at right?
2. Are there only `leqno` and `regno` options with LaTeX? But is there, for example, the `ceqno` option, i.e. the possibility of placing the number next to the equation (at the centre to be clearer) or that it is always at the centre but in the middle of the two equations?

Comment: why do you say "how come the leqno option is not active and the number is always put on the right?"  the equation number appears on the left when `leqno` is used.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Why `leqno` is not active with `align`?

Comment: it is active, you get the number on the left

Comment: The code is in the question not the answer so I added the image for leqno to your answer, you only showed the default right number. (there is no `regno` option)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I have deleted my previous comment after your edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a single number for the display, use `equation` not `align`
[image]

Note that there is no `reqno` option, equation numbers on the right is the default.

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a &= b+c \\
e &= f+g
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But can the number (1) be placed closer to the two equations always in the middle?

Comment: @Sebastiano equation numbers are always placed at the margin

Comment: @Sebastiano if you really wanted to change the margins you could use a minipage for example

Comment: I asked myself this question when I remember seeing a book of Physics in English that had the number of formulas nearby.

Comment: In the meantime, I totally accept your answer. Could you please show me with the minipage option how to put the progressive number of the equations close to the formula?

Comment: if you surround the display with say `\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}` then the number is only moved half way across the page (although using a minipage has other issues) @Sebastiano